# Issue with vertical line in multiline table

Tags: tables

I am facing issue with vertical line. It seems that the vertical line on the seccond level is thinner than the line on the first level. Below you will find a latex code and screenshot.
I appreciate your help!

```
\begin{table}[h]
\centering

\begin{tabular}{r|c|c|c|c|c}
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Number}}} & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\textbf{Object 1}} & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\textbf{Object 2}} & \multicolumn{1}{|c}{\textbf{Object 3}}\\
\textbf{} & \textbf{ 1 } & \textbf{ 2 } & \textbf{ 1 } & \textbf{ 2 } & \textbf{ 1 }  \\
\hline
 1 & 39 & 4 & 18 & 1 & \cellcolor{tableGreen}0 \\
 10 & 40 & 4 & 12 & \cellcolor{tableGreen}2 & 4 \\
 100 & 49 & 5 & 13 & \cellcolor{tableGreen}2 & 33 \\
 1000 & 15 & \cellcolor{tableGreen}12 & 174 & 12 & 211 \\

\end{tabular}
\caption{Messergebnisse für S1 zwischen Neo4j, Oracle und PostgreSQL in ms}
\label{Table_Selektion_S1}
\end{table}
```

[image]

Comment: You are repeating the vertical lines. Change to `\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Number}}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{Object 1}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{Object 2}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Object 3}}\\`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a MWE. You are repeating vertical lines.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{multirow}


\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{r|c|c|c|c|c}
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Number}}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{Object 1}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{Object 2}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Object 3}}\\
\textbf{} & \textbf{ 1 } & \textbf{ 2 } & \textbf{ 1 } & \textbf{ 2 } & \textbf{ 1 }  \\
\hline
 1 & 39 & 4 & 18 & 1 & \cellcolor{green}0 \\
 10 & 40 & 4 & 12 & \cellcolor{green}2 & 4 \\
 100 & 49 & 5 & 13 & \cellcolor{green}2 & 33 \\
 1000 & 15 & \cellcolor{green}12 & 174 & 12 & 211 \\

\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped!

Answer (score 0):

You do not need all `\multicolumn` in your table, also `\textbf{}` is meaningless. In needed `\multicolumn` you need vertical bar only on the right side of cells:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[table, dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[h]
    \centering
\begin{tabular}{r|c|c|c|c|c}
\multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Number}} 
        &   \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{Object 1}}      % <---
            &   \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{Object 2}}  % <---
                    &   \textbf{Object 3}       \\      % <---
    &   \textbf{ 1 }                                    % <---
        &   \textbf{ 2 } 
            &   \textbf{ 1 } 
                &   \textbf{ 2 } 
                    & \textbf{ 1 }  \\
\hline
 1      & 39 & 4 & 18 & 1 & \cellcolor{Green}0 \\
 10     & 40 & 4 & 12 & \cellcolor{Green}2 & 4 \\
 100    & 49 & 5 & 13 & \cellcolor{Green}2 & 33 \\
1000    & 15 & \cellcolor{Green}12 & 174 & 12 & 211 \\
\end{tabular}
\caption{Messergebnisse für S1 zwischen Neo4j, Oracle und PostgreSQL in ms}
\label{Table_Selektion_S1}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

*Note*: in above MWE is not used your color `tableGreen` since it is not known, how is defined. Please  always provide small but complete document example, which reproduce your problem.

Comment: Thanks, this helped! Yes, you are right regarding the document example. Also thank for this remark.